# Changing columns right to left in a tibble

Tags: r

I have a table - read from an excel file, with column names in English and some variables in Hebrew. 
As I read the excel file and receive a tibble, the column names don't fit the data.

I use the following code to read the table:

```
excel_file <- file.path(the file path, the file)

tab_1 <- read_xlsx(excel_file)
tab_1
```

The result that I'm getting:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  case      a     b     c     d
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 שחור      3     2     1     4
2 אדום      2     5     2     3
>
```

How can I change the order of the column names? I have looked all over and found no solution.

Comment: Could you add what would be your desired output/result?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by specifying the column indexes

Using the `iris` dataset as an example

First, change to a tibble

```
iris2 <- iris %>% as_tibble()
```

Reverse columns by manually specifying by column index

```
iris2[,c(5,4,3,2,1)]
```

Or do the same programatically

```
iris2[,ncol(iris2):1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a way easier solution than those I thought of.
Although when my tibble has more columns - it prints the columns left to right again.

Comment: @Amidavid the second method above should work for tibbles of any number of columns. Are you assigning the output?

Answer (score 0):

When the tibble becomes wider (more columns) the answer looks something like this

```
> tab_1 <- tab_1[,ncol(tab_1):1]
> print(tab_1)
# A tibble: 2 x 19
  result     q     p     o     n     m     l     k     j     i     h     g     f     e     d     c     b     a
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 שחור       2     4     5     6     4     6     2     1     2     5     2     3     4     4     1     2     3
2 אדום       4     3     5     5     6     3     0     3     3     4     5     3     5     3     2     5     2
  case 
  <chr>
1 שחור 
2 אדום
```

- changing back the column names of the first part

Answer (score 0):

I use the tidyverse generally for content management.  The select function is a clean single line to reverse df columns generally.  E.g.,

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- ncol(mtcars)
mtcars2 <- select(mtcars, c(n:1))
```

Comment: It gives the same result in which for a wide tibble (many columns) the first part printed is with the wrong column names

Comment: Printing to the console can distort the column alignments.  After you create your modified df, you can go to the RStudio Global Environment pane and select it by checking the select box on the right hand side.  That will show a clean df view with the proper alignments in the Source pane.

Answer (score 0):

An option is also to use `rev`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    select(rev(names(.)))
```

Comment: @Amidavid you need to assign it back `mtcars <- `